# API function to get the separator of function arguments

Tags: office-js

The separator (eg, `;` or `,`) of function arguments may be different from workbooks to workbooks. I would like to know what is the JavaScript function to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're setting `range.formulas` (as opposed to `range.formulasLocal`), you can and should use the English notation (which in this case is `,`). The same goes for formula names: you would use `=Sum` instead of `=Summe`.

If there's any scenario where that's not enough, I'd be curious to learn why...

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Indeed, even though i set `;` as list separator in the `Control Panel => Region => Customise Format`, `range.formulas` automatically changes `;` to `,` when loaded...